# Error with junit:junit:4.12 , javax:index:inject:1 , javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Please Help me, I've tried everything, I've tried everything, several answers, but nothing. Why does not Gradle work?

Here my mistakes
[image: my mistakes]

Comment: I already resolved it, Possibly because the connection you have, do not allow you to download the corresponding libraries for the project, because, your network has blocked the proxy. Greetings. PD: I hope it works for someone. :)